# HTTP server configuration internal error 500

Tags: http, subversive, internal-server-error, collabnet

I have set up collabnet subversion edge server and I have installed subversion team provider for eclipse . I had a problem about connecting to my repositories but later on I have solved it somehow . Now , I want to configure LDAP with active directory but I have some problems . I get internal 500 error when I try committing a project . How can I fix that problem?

Share project was failed.
svn: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/rep/!svn/act/7c716dbe-3801-0010-8bbe-21e116bed3a7': 500 Internal Server Error (http://localhost)
svn: MKACTIVITY request failed on '/svn/rep/!svn/act/7c716dbe-3801-0010-8bbe-21e116bed3a7'

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is an HTTP code, not an LDAP error message.

Comment: im sorry im new to networks ,i dont have strong knowledge about LDAP and AD ,too ..I have configured LDAP in collabnet subversion edge ,but now I can't import a file to the repository in eclipse even if im admin. It justs wants my username and password many times but doesnt work at all .. what can be the problem ? how can i solve it ? if you have any idea , feel free to say . Thanks ..

Comment: How can you solve what? You do need to state in some detail what you're doing, what systems are involved, what you changed, what you tried, what the results were, and what results you expected. You've done none of that; you don't appear to even understand what you're doing; and you've shown no evidence of having investigated systematically. You are never going to solve anything this way. I suggest you enlist the aid of a colleague.